# Writing Android apps in C# (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mono

I'm a C# programmer and want to write an Android app. I'm a stubborn curmudgeon and refuse to write Java ever again (after switching to C# six years ago).

Besides Mono and MonoDroid (and writing Java), are there any options for me? Or should I just feel foolish for refusing to returning to my Java roots?

What's the advantages and disadvantages of ***Xamarin*** over others like *Phonegap* etc. ?

(Please refrain from Java-related vs. C# discussion. I was being rhetorical when I asked about returning to me Java roots.)

Comment: Wait for Monodroid, else http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-koushikdutta-mono-iDA.aspx

Comment: have there been any updates since 6/10?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that [this](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2009/01/building-mono-for-android.html) is basically the only option for c# developers.

Comment: No. MonoDroid provides something more, such as better UI binding.

Comment: Link is dead. Thought it was on purpose .

Answer (score 1):

Developing a mobile application these days is an arduous task.  You need to have a mobile app to get your business noticed and to gain market share with your audience, however which platform do you choose?  Apple?  Android?  Windows Phone?
Cost of developing a mobile app is one of the biggest hurdles besides the choice of platform.  To get an application developed natively in two of the three major mobile operating systems immediately doubles the cost of development.
Each mobile operating system is designed around development in a specific programming language and development environment.

3 different operating systems, 3 separate languages and development environments, and counting.  To be able to cater to all of these operating systems natively, mobile app developers need to have someone able to be an expert in each of these programming languages and also be an expert in the nuances of how each mobile operating system works.  Task lifecycles, multi-threading, memory limitations, garbage collection, etc.

More more about Xamarin :

http://devproconnections.com/mobile-development/product-review-xamarin-monotouch-and-mono-android

http://www.justinshield.com/2014/05/cross-platform-mobile-development-phonegap-vs-xamarin/

Answer (score 0):

MonoDroid is worth the wait,

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/May-21.html

Answer (score 0):

> Besides Mono and MonoDroid (and
>   writing Java), are there any options
>   for me?

Another option is Scala. I'm not sure what the tooling is like right now though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a dedicated C# developer, I think that [MonoDroid](http://www.mono-droid.com) is the right answer for you. MonoDroid Preview 1 has been released 2 days ago, so there won't be long until the beta and full release.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is another option, it is possible to create android as well as IOS apps with it and you can use Visual Studio or use our full featured MonoDevelop IDE.

http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid